# How do you enable a CAC card in Firefox on linux?

Tags: linux, smartcard

I want to enable a Common Access Smart card on CentOS 5.3 x86_64 in Firefox.

What is the easiest procedure to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Launch Firefox 3.x.
2. Go to Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Encryption
3. Click on Security Devices
4. Click on Load
5. Browse to or type the path as `/usr/lib64/pkcs11/libcoolkeypk11.so`
6. Rename the Module as you see fit, `CoolKey PKCS#11 Module` for example.
7. Click on Ok.

This assumes that all of the smartcard drivers and libraries are already available and loaded properly.  It appears that on a Dell Precision T5400 with the Dell SmartCard USB keyboard, the CentOS 5.3 install DVD has all of the parts to make it go.  You might need to find the coolkey library or pcsclite and install them first.

I've seen these steps on a number of other pages, but I figured it out before I found the pages.

Comment: Just as a followup: this is now located under Advanced->Certificates. In addition, once the CAC was inserted, my name/cert appeared in the `Security Devices` window; I had to select that, choose "Log In", and enter my PIN that way. Then my CAC worked within Firefox.